# ASP.NET Web Api configuring a specific route not executing message handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to configure a specific route to execute a message handler before it hits the controller, however the message handler is never executed.

I have the following controller:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("private/users")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

And the following route configuration:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "private/users",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            handler: new TokenValidationHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) }
        );
```

And The MessageHandler looks like this:

```
public class TokenValidationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //some logic to validate token
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The TokenValidationHandler is never executed which seems to be because of the routeTemplate when configuring the route. Is it possible to achieve route specific configuration with a hardcoded routeTemplate like *"private/users"* instead of the default *"{controller}/{id}"* format?

What I want to do is have my TokenValidationHandler fire for all of my private api calls and have public api calls bypass the TokenValidationHandler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute routes a matched before convention-based routes. The action in question is tagged with an `Route` attribute. If attribute routing is enabled then it means that it will not reach the convention-based route and thus not invoke the handler.

Remove the route attribute

```
public class TestController : ApiController { 
    public IHttpActionResult Get() {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The order of route registration also plays a factor for convention-based routes so make sure that general routes are registered after more specific routes

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "PrivateApi",
    routeTemplate: "private/users",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: null,
    handler: new TokenValidationHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) }
);

//more general route
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    //...
);
```

Otherwise if attribute routing is your preference you can consider using an [action filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).

Based on stated intentions you would be better off using [Authentication Filters in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am already using attribute routing throughout my application. Does that mean I must use an action filter to achieve the route based configuration I need?

Comment: @shane87, Yes. Consider using an authentication filter.